# Accessing VirtualMachine Interface for Azure SDK Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-sdk

I am trying to get Virtual Machine compute name, which can be accessed by Virtual Machine Interface of com.microsoft.azure.management.compute package, but I am not able to access this particular interface, Link to the interface and its methods https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/VirtualMachine.html

Answer (score 0):

As I know, this issue is due to the version of the azure java SDK.
When I use old versions such as 0.8.0, I encounter the same problem.
So, I use the newest version and I can see the VirtualMachine interface Class.

You could use the newest version by  maven repository .
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-mgmt-compute.

Hope it helps. Any concerns, please feel free to let me know.